# Using graphicsmagick, what is a good way to find the coordinates of a small image inside a bigger image?

Tags: python, graphics, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

#### Question:

Using [graphicsmagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/), what is a good way to find the coordinates of a small image inside a bigger image?

#### Explnation:

To explain further, I have a large screen shot that I am working with and would like to find the pixel coordinates of a known icon that is expected to be found somewhere within the screen shot.

Also, if this is not a good library to be using for this purpose, would love to hear suggestions for alternatives that will preferably be compatible with Python.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use "gm display" to do that.

```
gm display &
```

Click on the image. Select Transform, then Crop. Put the cursor at the
top left of the small image. Read the coordinates from the small
information window. Select "dismiss"

Note that this is a manual method, which is OK if you are really "working
with the image" on screen.  If you are looking for a batch method, it'll
be a little more complex.